# Excel comparing two columns and creating a new column

Tags: excel, vlookup

Okay, this is a bit of a confusing question. I have a two column excel document.
Column A contains sentences with names.
Column B contains Full names (first and last)

Thanks!

Comment: can you elaborate your approach ... which name you want to print in the third column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this will get you started in the right direction.  Using your example, in cell C2 and copied down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$4,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(COUNTIF(A2,"*"&TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE($B$2:$B$4," ",REPT(" ",99)),99))&"*")>0,),0)),"No Matches")
```

Comment: This worked for what I need it to do, thanks! Is there anyway you could explain this to me so I know exactly what I am doing?

Answer (score 0):

I would copy over your column "B" to a new sheet to save it. I would then text to columns for the second column on spaces. I would put this new function in the sixth column

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(B1,A1))=TRUE,IF(ISERROR(FIND(C1,A1))=TRUE,IF(ISERROR(FIND(D1,A1))=TRUE,IF(ISERROR(FIND(F1,A1))=TRUE,"Name not found",FIND(F1,A1)),FIND(D1,A1)),FIND(C1,A1)),FIND(B1,A1))
```

Comment: What if the OP has 10 different name cells to check? 100? This is not a scalable solution :(